# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ Categories: Element; Admin: Element; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm quite new to TS and would like to understand why I get a type error in the following code (simplified):

```js
"use client";

import { ArrowDownWideNarrow, Settings } from "lucide-react";

interface LinkItemProps {
  name: string;
}

const iconMap = {
  Categories: <ArrowDownWideNarrow />,
  Admin: <Settings />,
};

export const LinkItem = ({ name }: LinkItemProps) => {
  <div>
    {iconMap[name]}
  </div>
}
```

The error is in the `{iconMap[name]}:

`"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ Categories: Element; Admin: Element; }'.`

`No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ Categories: Element; Admin: Element; }'."`

The `parent element` has the following:

```js
const LINKS = [
  {
    href: "/admin",
    name: "Admin",
    id: "admin",
  },
  {
    href: "/categories",
    name: "Categories",
    id: "categories",
  },
];

export const Sidebar = async () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {LINKS.map((link) => (
        <div key={link.href}>
          <LinkItem href={link.href} id={link.id} name={link.name} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can narrow the type of `name` with `interface LinkItemProps { name: keyof typeof iconMap }` to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ Categories: Element; Admin: Element; }'."

The `string` type is too *wide*, you could be more specific on the `name` prop type so it properly inherits the fields based on the `iconMap` object.

**[Typescript demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQSlCB3AIpgdgdWABMBTAOQEM1MAaOAZRJhmFwHMBnOAXzgDN0IOACIANgFcAxsRIBaKCQqSYwgNwAoUJFhwASouX9BcAOQKlMExs24YJKHyUk4AGVYBrAJJ2QABXRgXAjqcHC4FCAkAFxw7iQAnhB8cDDxYCRJcMCSELgAshRgGtzq6jm4HPDZuQVgcAC8iCFwAMIUdmzQwCQcMQA8qOjYeISklNQYcAD0AHw0zchEIKz9jMysnNNz6tzWJAAe2vDlla4e3iRCjQAUSOGRPDFuuF4+-hCBAJQNM02hfURgAA3GbNUIIar5QoAbXuJAAuiV-lNASCdkA)**

```
interface LinkItemProps {
  name: keyof typeof iconMap;
}
```

or a manual, strictly typed approach:

```
interface LinkItemProps {
  name: 'Categories' | 'Admin';
}
```

**[Updated typescript demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQSlCB3AIpgdgdWABMBTAOQEM1MAaOAZRJhmFwHMBnOAXzgDN0IOACIANgFcAxsRIBaKCQqSYwgNwAoUJFhwASouX9BcAOQKlMExvUlc4oQElJEXAFE7QhOrhwAwhRgSNmhgEi4AXlN-QOCoUI4TOmQiEFY4SJNk1NxE9W51TVxAqD4lEjgAGVYAawdAkAAFdDAuLx9cChASAC44Jxd3ew0fAAsFPl6OGDj2YbhiSenWNg189WdcKfmNgFkKMF79ZygiAB5%20tw86fQsAOhvlMghSAD50xG8-AKCQsN7T1DobB4QikSjUDBwAD0LxonyyrH%20jGYyy4MLh3GsJAAHtp4BstlVcLV6u8ABRIDpdHi9IkkkiNZocACU6TebTgChg4iguDgZM%20PlORGAADcXoKfIhgLt9gBtKkkAC6%20SlcFOUJF4s%20zNWBQJ8AqDjIAGl6O85Z8OaNxr1hFCKClWMI4WrFXaEbgXZKFiJHdlvT5uK6PmqxiQJiIoZJvrF4oGpe6RNEfnEwgmfL7hDGYr8OAng%20olVjcdB8S4tvQZAAjKjvCgcACeuEk-NZ4XZny5PL5ArVwrFErVPgQRtN9FuIH2ZLJohq7befeHQq1cGqJEb4QQc%20Jt3DfG4Q%20XUtOdLqDLg%2063O%20qe-GvGI15qt2IvEVT93irgDb6G0GIF4GFJX7TVB2AuBmWZVUT1A7UfGZPIgA)**

Comment: Thank you very much, kind user ;)
But now I have an error in the parent element (I edited my question to include the parent).
The error is there now saying: "Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"Categories" | "Admin"'."
That's in property "name" in the LinkItem inside the `map`.
Thank you, I understand my question must be quite basic :)

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta Check my "Updated typescript demo"

Comment: That indeed cleared all errors, thank you! Now I'll try to digest it :D